# Change thickness programmatically

Tags: android, xml

HI I am developing an application for Android. In my activity it contains one Relative layout. I want to set the ring type background. So I use the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:thickness="200dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid
        android:color="#0f000000"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

It is working fine. Now **I want to change the thickness in above code programmatically. How can I change this**?

Comment: The thickness property of the GradientDrawable (shapes are Gradients) is not exposed, so it can only be set in the xml. I guess you have to make a custom View and draw it on canvas.